# how to put text inside the input of a page that i opened with iframe?

Tags: php, iframe

I need to open a page from another site on my site and add text in the inputs of that page, so I used iframe to open it, but I don't know how to add the text in the inputs. Can someone help me?

Comment: You can only access the iframe content if your site and the site you're loading in the iframe have the same domain/origin. If you're loading a different domain/origin in an iframe, you won't be able to access/modify the contents from the parent.

Comment: You could run `file_get_contents` then modify the source of the page. You can't control an iframes content though.

Comment: The iframe is from another site, I need to send the user to a page on the internet and inside the page I need to put the text in some inputs automatically for him

Comment: It is possible? It doesn't have to be with iframe, I was just using it because I thought it would be easier

Comment: file_get_contents is just to read the page content isn't it? How are I going to insert text into the inputs?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to achieve this would be if the page you're loading in the iframe allows GET parameters to be passed in with the URL. The form elements on the target site would then have to use the values as default for them to be displayed on load.

E.g.:

```
https://target.com/?formFieldOne=hello
```

Then the code of the target page would have to be something similar to this:

```
<input type="text" value="<?PHP echo($_GET['formFieldOne']); ?>" />
```